# Sharepoint 2010 Notifications not working

Tags: alert

I'm trying to set up notifications in a production enviroment. I have already set up the notifications in a test enviroment which contains the same SMTP-adress that I need to use in production.

The problem is the following:

- I get no initial mail when I set up the notification.
- When I look in the ImmedSubscriptions table, in the sharepoint database, it's empty.

I have cheked the following:

- SMTP adress
- Exchange configuration
- Sharepoint timer jobs

Any suggestions for how I can further troubleshoot this problem ?

UPDATE:
It turned out that the network wasn't configured correctly on the production environment. We ended up solving it by writing the IP-adress directly in the Central Administration instead of the SMTP address on both the farm and the Web Application.
The production environment has since been configured correctly.

If anyone else is experiencing this problem I can recommend trying to use Telnet. That lead me in the correct direction.
By using telnet I got "530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated".
In short, if you can't send an e-mail with telnet then Sharepoint can send mail either.

If in doubt how to use Telnet to send an E-mail, here is a guide:
http://www.rdpslides.com/webresources/FAQ00035_Send_Email_via_Telnet.htm

Comment: Are you using managed metadata columns by any case? that will cause the notification to break!

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani Please clarify what you mean. Managed Metadata columns do *not* break alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this troubleshooting guide

http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/

[image: SharePoint Alert troubleshooting flowchart]
<sub>(source: [sharepointalert.info](http://sharepointalert.info/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/flowchart.gif))</sub>

Start with the simple stuff - can you use an SMTP test tool to send an email from the SharePoint server successfully? I suspect you will find that your email server isn't configured to 'trust' (aka relay) emails coming from your SharePoint server.

Answer (score 1):

**Email configuration**

Note that there are 2 places to configure the SMTP settings. Have you set the SMTP values for the Farm, or the Web Application?

Farm: `http://NotReallyMyCompany.com:MgmtPort/_admin/globalemailconfig.aspx`

WebApplication: `http://NotReallyMyCompany.com:MgmtPort/_admin/WebApplicationList.aspx`

- select web app

  - General settings (in ribbon)

    - Outgoing Email

**User Configuration**

Does the user information list show the email address of the user that you are creating these alerts with? (Sometimes there is a delay in getting this info from the User Profile Service- if you are using that)

- Click on your user name

  - My Settings

**Alert Configuration**

Can you create alerts manually from the GUI?

What do you see in the manage my alerts area for the user who is supposed to be getting the alerts?

**Randomness Reduction**

Have you created custom alert templates?

Have you created alerts by script or by code?

Are your production servers black/white listed with your SMTP relays?

Answer (score 0):

Try with powershell email configuration

http://mikefrobbins.com/2011/08/04/configure-sharepoint-2010-outgoing-email-settings-with-powershell/